# How to post one variable in ajax call to multiple php file's?

Tags: php, html, ajax, variables, post

How to post one variable in ajax call to multiple  php file's using URL method..
My data is as follow..

```
<select name="districts" id="district_list" class="update" onChange="getDist(this.value)" >
    <option value="d1">east</option>
    <option value="d2">west</option>        
</select>
```

I want to pass these id value to another two php files using ajax  and i tried as follow..

```
function getState(val) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_dist.php",
    url: "get_city.php",    
    data:'states_id='+val,
    success: function(data){            
        $("#district_list").html(data);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: It's not possible. Either do multiple ajax calls or a single call to a script that makes it's own calls (cURL ?)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<select name="districts" id="district_list" class="update" onChange="getDist(this.value) ; getCity(this.value)" >
    <option value="d1">east</option>
    <option value="d2">west</option>
</select>

    <script>

    function getDist(val){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_dist.php",
            data:'states_id='+val,
            success: function(data){
            $("#district_list").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function getCity(val){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_city.php",    
            data:'states_id='+val,
            success: function(data){
            $("#city_list").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```